# Having error in Tableau when run a custom queries

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

Kindly assist with this tableau error , Everything in the workbook runs fine while live but when I try to extract the data, I receive the error:

An error occurred while communicating with the Other Databases (ODBC) data source 'CustomerDetailwLifeCycle1 (local copy)'

Error Code: 1E953F46
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Explicit conversion from data type date to timestamp is not allowed.
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

I keep getting this error.
My queries are quite lengthy and cannot as txt and If pasting it required, I'll gladly paste it.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: The error is pretty explicit here. i would start looking at where you have a `timestamp` column, as a table can only have one `rowversion` column.

Comment: Do you mind If I paste my query for you to see, still can figure it out. Your assistance is of great importance

Comment: Ypu can, but without the DDL that may not tell me where the problem is.

Comment: One test you could try - from tableau, hide the date and datetime fields in your data source before creating the extract. Since hidden fields won't be included in the extract, they should bypass your problem. If so, you can then selectively unhide fields until you determine which one is the problem.

Comment: When you connected to your database from Tableau, i.e. created the Tableau data source, did you connect via the SQL Server driver or the ODBC driver? You can tell by looking at the Properties of the data source in Tableau and checking the Type. Sometimes the driver built specifically for a particular DBMS will perform better than the generic ODBC driver

Comment: I connected through ODBC driver